# How to set the top/bottom margins of a Win32 richedit

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, controls

We can use [EM_SETMARGINS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761649(VS.85).aspx) message to set the left/right margins of a RichEdit control. But I don't know how to set the top/bottom margins. Is any body knows? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [EM_GETRECT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761596(v=vs.85).aspx) / [EM_SETRECT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761657(v=vs.85).aspx) message combination to modify all the margins:

```
        RECT rc;
        // Get the current control rectangle
        SendMessage(hWndRichEdit, EM_GETRECT, 0, (LPARAM)&rc);
        rc.left += 20; // increase the left margin 
        rc.top += 20; // increase the top margin
        rc.right -= 20; // decrease the right margin
        rc.bottom -= 20; // decrease the bottom margin (rectangle)
        // Set the rectangle
        SendMessage(hWndRichEdit, EM_SETRECT, 0, (LPARAM)&rc);
```

The resulting control has all four margins:

[image: RichEdit control with 20px margins]

**Update**: As per `Barmak Shemirani` and `IInspectable` comments below you could use the [GetClientRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633503(v=vs.85).aspx) function to get the current rectangle and [InflateRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/dd144994(v=vs.85).aspx) function to manipulate the rectangle / margin dimensions.

Comment: You probably want to use `GetClientRect` instead of `EM_GETRECT`. Because `EM_GETRECT` returns the current margin. For example left/top margin could be returned as 1 and 1. Whereas `GetClientRect` always returns 0 and 0.

Comment: Little known, the Windows API offers a number of [rectangle functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162901.aspx). The code in this answer could be changed to take advantage of [InflateRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144994.aspx), for example: `InflateRect(rc, -20, -20);`.